# Trying to create a remember me function using jquery and session cookies, but app won't even load when running it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, cookies, remember-me

I am trying to create a remember me function using session cookies and jquery. However, when I run the app, it will not even load, so I can't see if the actual feature itself is working. This is my first opportunity trying to do this, so any tips or leads are more than welcome!

Installing: I downloaded the jquery.cookie using NuGet using: Install-Package jquery.cookie -Version 1.4.1

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<body class="login-page">
        <div class="login-box">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card border-radius5">
                <div class="body">
                    <form id="sign_in" method="POST" class="my-form">
                        <div class="msg font-25">Sign In</div>
                           <div class="input-group">
                             <div class="form-line"> 
                              <input id="signinemail" 
                                   type="email" 
                                   value="Email" 
                                   class="form-control" 
                                   name="Email" 
                                   placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="form-line">
                                <input id="signinpassword" 
                                       type="password" 
                                       value="Password" 
                                       class="form-control" 
                                       name="Password" 
                                       placeholder="Password" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-8 p-t-5">
                                <input type="checkbox" 
                                       checked="RememberMe" 
                                       name="RememberMe" 
                                       id="RememberMe" 
                                       class="filled-in chk-col-teal">
                                <label for="RememberMe">Remember Me</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button id="signin" class="btn bg-teal btn-block btn-lg waves-effect" type="submit">SIGN IN</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
 <script>
  $(document).on(function() {

  fillByMemory()
  $('button#signin').on('click', function() {

    if ($('#RememberMe').val()) {
      rememberMe();
    }


    doLogin();
  });



});

function rememberMe() {
  $.cookie('id', $('#signinemail').val());
  $.cookie('pass', $('#signinpassword').val());

}

function fillByMemory() {
  if (!!$.cookie('id'))
    $('signinemail').val($.cookie('id'));

  if (!!$.cookie('pass'))
    $('#signinpassword').val($.cookie('pass'));
}
        </script>
```

Comment: Side note; storing user credentials in cookies is a security issue.

Comment: @Taplar.  Thanks - Is there a package out there you recommend me using?

Comment: Browsers already have the ability to remember form credentials for websites that will have security around it vastly more secure than anything javascript could do in page.

Comment: Otherwise, if you are wanting a true "remember me" situation, it sounds like you are after authorization tokens that are stored in the browser, that the server remembers and associates with the user for a period of time.  Implementing that though falls outside the realm of javascript though.